# linux bash: line 18: syntax error near unexpected token `fi' Q2.sh: line 18: `fi'

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to compile this code but I am getting the following error:

```
Q2.sh: line 18: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
Q2.sh: line 18: `fi'
```

at line 15, I'm trying to verify if the parameter `numero` is bigger than 0. Any help is appreciated

Thanks

```
#!bin/bash

numero=$1

if test $# -eq 0; then
    echo "Argument Manquants"
    exit 1
fi

if ! [[ "$numero" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ; then
    exec >&2; echo "Le parametre doit etre un digit";
    exit 1
fi

if [ $numero -le 0 ]
$$  echo "Le parametre doit etre plus grand que 0"  
    exit 1
fi

cat /etc/passwd grep "$numero"
```

Comment: Shell scripts are normally interpreted, not compiled.

Comment: You probably want `grep -w "$numero" /etc/passwd` down at the end. Usually `getent` is preferred over direct manipulation of the `/etc/passwd` file.

Comment: The second check already rules out any negative numbers, as you do not allow a minus sign. So you could just check that it's not zero. (Zero is a valid UID though, why do you want to disallow it?)

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the `; then` part in your `if` clause:

```
if [ "$numero" -le 0 ]; then
    ...
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've missed the `then` statement at the end of your `if`, and you've only used single square brackets. Try replacing that block for this:

```
if [[ $numero -le 0 ]]; then
    echo "Le parametre doit etre plus grand que 0"  
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Single square brackets are not wrong here, although you might want to be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue, when i copied the script edited on a windows to unix system. On debut run, I get the same error.

When i edited the file once within the editor on destination m/c, the script ran without issues.

To me it seems to be character encoding issue. But i am still searching for solution for overcoming it in my case.

May be it helps a bit.